# Why my Multiplication Table is not showing?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can't figure it out what is wrong with my `onsubmit` event:
When I press Submit - nothing is happening. When I put cols and rows directly in function show table it works. Here's a link to codepen http://codepen.io/Y-Taras/pen/VaaBgy

```
 window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("show").onsubmit = function() {
     var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;
     cols = parseInt(cols);
     var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
     rows = parseInt(rows);
     showTable(rows, cols);
     console.log(rows, cols);
   };

   function showTable(rows, cols) {....
```

```js
 window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("show").onsubmit = function() {
     var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;
     cols = parseInt(cols);
     var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
     rows = parseInt(rows);
     showTable(rows, cols);
     console.log(rows, cols);
   };

   function showTable(rows, cols) {
     var elem = "<table>";
     for (var i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++) {
       elem += "<tr>";
       for (var j = 1; j < cols + 1; j++) {
         elem += "<td> " + i * j + "</td>";
         if (j === cols) {
           elem += "</tr>";
         }
       }
     }
     elem += "</table>";
     document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = elem;
   }
 };
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>javascript</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Multiplication Table</p>
  <hr/>
  <form>
    Number of rows:
    <input type="text" id="rows" name="rows">Number of cols:
    <input type="text" id="cols" name="cols">
    <input id="show" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `onsubmit` event, you must have a form, so add a form tag to your html, covering all the inputs.

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="rows" name="rows">Number of cols:
    <input type="text" id="cols" name="cols">
    <input id="show" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Change the id for the `onsubmit` event to the id of your form, and add `return false` to the end of your code in the `onsubmit`, like this:

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
    // ......
    // your code above

    return false;
}
```

This will prevent the page from refreshing after you click on the submit button.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet "show" is a button, not a form. So you need to use "onclick" instead of "onsubmit".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the type of the input, it's got to be a "button" not "submit"!